# How to ignore the first 2 bot reactions?

Tags: discord.js

Im trying to test for when someone reacts to one of the 2 emojis that the bot posts on the embed, but when the bot reacts with  on the embed it triggers the  if (reaction.emoji.name === '') statement and im not sure how to ignore the bot doing its first 2 reactions which people can react to

```
let msg2 = await orderChannel.send({embed: embed});
msg2.react('✅');
msg2.react('');
 const reactions = await msg2.awaitReactions(reaction => reaction.emoji.name == '✅' || reaction.emoji.name == '', {time: 86400000, max: 1});
 let reaction = await reactions.first();

if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
    await msg2.delete();
    await msg.author.send(`Your order was completed. Please come to the pharmacy with $ ${howmany}000`);
    return;
};

if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
    await msg2.delete();
    await msg.author.send(`Your order has been delayed, please message Pixel for info.`);
    return;
};
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work best in my opinion. The filter checks for the check emoji and author or the D emoji and author. Thus if the bot, or anybody else for that matter, reacts, it ignores it.

```
let filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name == '✅' && user.id == msg.author.id || reaction.emoji.name == '' && user.id == msg.author.id;
const reactions = await msg2.awaitReactions(filter, {time: 86400000, max: 1});
```

> This works well as AND (&&) executes before OR (||).

I also adjusted the formatting just a little to make it easier to read. (seperated into a filter variable)

Answer (score 0):

The quickest workaround I could think of was using the `MessageReaction.count` property, which counts the number of the reaction in question in the message. In your case, you could probably say
`if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅' && reaction.count > 1) {. . .}`